# How to show different menu bar CSS in wordpress navbar / menu bar?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have created two (2) menu bar in WordPress.  In this two menu bar, I have  set them into two **separated** **CSS style**. My problems is the CSS is **Not showing** on my secondary navbar / menu bar. Can anyone help me with this?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the markup and css that's specific to the menu bars?

Comment: @bbodien they are just separated CSS file. Just some basic bootstrap nav bar and style. Hmm, I think is something like don't make two of the CSS file 'conflict' ??

Comment: First check that both css files are being loaded correctly and you haven't made a typo in the path of the `link` tags. Then use your browser's inspector tools to examine the styles being applied to the elements. If the selectors aren't being picked up, check the selector syntax. CSS files shouldn't conflict - they'll cascade (the C in the acronym), so one might overrule another, depending on which rule is more specific (generally the more complex selector will take precedence).

Comment: @bbodien I am certain that the CSS file was loaded succefully. Because the other section also loaded the same CSS file. Or is it something i missing to add on my header.php?

Comment: It's really difficult to say without being able to inspect the site myself. If you can create a codepen or code snippet here with an example illustrating the problem, that would help.

Comment: @bbodien Let me explain more to you. 1. I have two CSS file, the first one is called style.css and the second one is called others.css. 2. I had set my primary menu bar's CSS to style.css file and set my secondary menu bar's CSS to others.css file. So, my problem is the secondary menu bar is not using the others.css file to load the secondary menu bar's style.  Hope you can help me with this! :)

Comment: Inspect the secondary menu bar, look at the `id` and `class` attributes and make a note of what values they have, then look in `others.css`, and find the selectors that you think should be applying in order to style the menu bar. Edit all that info into your question, then it might be solvable.